# What is the initial contents of /usr/local on macOS 10.13?

Tags: high-sierra

I'd like to reset `/usr/local` to whatever it would be if I reformatted my mac and reinstalled macOS 10.13

Is that state documented? If there was content there is there a way to reset it back to it's original state?

Comment: It is empty so `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/*`

Comment: Does 10.13 have `pkgutil` available?

Comment: @fd0 What has that to do with the question? I don't know but in 10.12 it is /usr/sbin/pkgutil so I would guess so

Comment: @Mark pkgutil can list the Apple installed packages and can list files installed by those packages. On 10.12, the package-com.apple.pkg.RemoteDesktopClient is installed in /usr/local.

Comment: Looking at time in `/usr/sbin/pkgutil --file-info /usr/local` the package-com.apple.pkg.RemoteDesktopClient is not part of the standard install